# Why do I sometimes get System.IO.IOException: The file '/sdcard' already exists on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, file-io, xamarin.android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

In our production app we rarely get this exception which causes our app to crash: **System.IO.IOException: The file '/sdcard' already exists**

The app is a Xamarin.Forms app written in C# and runs on thousands of our own devices with Android 8.1 and 10. At every app start in the constructor of the `App` class we create a connection to an `SQLite` database. The database file is stored on the external storage under `/sdcard/mycompany/somesubfolder`. The devices don't use real SD-cards as storage though but the built-in storage.

Here is the method where the exception is thrown.

```
protected SQLiteAsyncConnection CreateDatabaseConnection(string databaseFilePath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(databaseFilePath))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(databaseFilePath), "Argument cannot be null, empty or whitespace!");

    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(databaseFilePath);

    try
    {
        if (directory != null && !Directory.Exists(directory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var metaData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "DatabaseFilePath", databaseFilePath },
            { "Directory", directory }
        };

        LoggingService.ReportException(ex, metaData);

        throw;
    }

    return CreateAsyncDbConnection(databaseFilePath);
}
```

In case of the exception both `databaseFilePath` and `directory` have proper values and are not `null`.

The `databaseFilePath` is created with `Path.Combine()` and consists of the following parts:

- storage path: **sdcard** (determined with `Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath`)
- bundle identifier: **com.mycompany.myapp** (determined with `ApplicationInfo.PackageName`)
- database folder: **database** (hardcoded string)
- database file name: **mydatabasefile.db3** (hardcoded string)

and looks like this:
`/sdcard/com.mycompany.myapp/database/mydatabasefile.db3`

The directory is the same but without the database file name:
`/sdcard/com.mycompany.myapp/database`

The exception does not occur a second time when the app is started again on the same device.

We also track our crashes with AppCenter. This is the reported stack trace:

```
FileSystem.CreateDirectory (System.String fullPath)
Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path)
DatabaseConnectionProviderBase.CreateDatabaseConnection (System.String databaseFilePath)
```

Comment: `Directory.Exists`  You should check with Directory.CanWrite if you can create a subfolder somewhere. Not Android 10 if not requested legacy external storage. And certainly not on Android 11+ devices.

Comment: `both databaseFilePath and directory have proper values ` Can be. But the problem with your code is that we cannot see which paths you use and as you have problems with using paths... you better put those paths in your code as well.

Comment: @blackapps The exception that you asked for is mentioned in the title.

Comment: @blackapps The `databaseFilePath` looks like this: `/sdcard/appbundleidentifier/database/mydatabasefile.db3`. The directory looks like `/sdcard/appbundleidentifier/database`.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you. I updated my question and added more information.

Comment: `The exception does not occur a second time when the app is started again on the same device.` Then why dont you tell on the first line of your post that your problem only occurs at first start of app? Instead of talking about 'rarely'.